# No me muestra el resultado deseado

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con mi código estoy tratando de mostrar unos nombres según un patrón, pero me muestra solo los 3 primeros nombres: y necesito que muestre los 4 nombre según el patrón adjunto de como se debería ver:

```
8/16/2021 On call: Max
8/17/2021 On call: Max
8/18/2021 On call: Paula
8/19/2021 On call: Paula
8/20/2021 On call: Roger
8/21/2021 On call: Roger
8/22/2021 On call: Roger
8/23/2021 On call: Daniela
8/24/2021 On call: Daniela
8/25/2021 On call: Max
8/26/2021 On call: Max
```

debido a que el patron es este **[2,2,3]**

y los nombres son estos:  **['Max','Paula','Roger','Daniela']**;

pero los muestra de la siguiente forma:

```
8/16/2021 On call: Max
8/17/2021 On call: Max
8/18/2021 On call: Paula
8/19/2021 On call: Paula
8/20/2021 On call: Roger
8/21/2021 On call: Roger
8/22/2021 On call: Roger
8/23/2021 On call: Max
8/24/2021 On call: Max
8/25/2021 On call: Paula
8/26/2021 On call: Paula
```

y no se que hacer:
adjunto el codigo

```
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

        function whoIsOnCall(pStartDate, pDate, pPattern, pGroup) {
          if (pDate < pStartDate) {
        return "ERROR: pDate must be greater than pStartDate";
        }

        const timeDifference = Math.floor((pDate - pStartDate) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
       const patternIndex = timeDifference % pPattern.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);

       for (let i = 0, currentIndex = 0; i < pPattern.length; i++) {
        currentIndex += pPattern[i];
        if (patternIndex < currentIndex) {
            return pGroup[i];
        }
    }

    return "no one is on call";
   }



      let vStartDate = new Date(2021, 7, 16);
      let myPattern = [2, 2, 3]; // Nuevo patrón con 2 días para cada persona
      let myGroup = ['Max', 'Paula', 'Roger', 'Daniela']; // Grupo de personas con Daniela
      let endDate = new Date(2021, 8, 12); // Fecha final: 9/12/2021
      let currentDate = new Date(vStartDate);

      while (currentDate <= endDate) {
      const onCallName = whoIsOnCall(vStartDate, currentDate, myPattern, myGroup);
       console.log(currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US') + ' On call: ' + onCallName);
       currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1); // Avanza al siguiente día
       }
```

muchas gracias, si alguien me puede colaborar

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el índice que obtienes solo te dice en que índice del patrón `[2,2,3]` estás, no a quien corresponde ese momento del patrón.

Tienes que calcular el desfase que hay en los turnos ya que tienes 3 turnos por semana y tienes 4 trabajadores. dado este ejemplo solo tienes que sumar el desfase en esa semana (3 por semana) entonces la segunda semana comenzara con el índice 3 (3 desfase + 0 por ser el primer turno de la semana):

```
function whoIsOnCall(pStartDate, pDate, pPattern, pGroup) {
      if (pDate < pStartDate) {
    return "ERROR: pDate must be greater than pStartDate";
    }

    //diferencia de tiempo en dias
    const timeDifference = Math.floor((pDate - pStartDate) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    //días de turno sin completar un cilco del patron
   const patternIndex = timeDifference % pPattern.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
   //calcular cuantos turnos completos han transcurrido
   const totalTurnos =  (timeDifference - patternIndex) / pPattern.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
   //calcular desfase de turnos según la cant de trabajadores
   const deltaGroup =  (totalTurnos * pPattern.lenght) % pGroup.lenght;

   for (let i = 0, currentIndex = 0; i < pPattern.length; i++) {
    currentIndex += pPattern[i];
    if (patternIndex < currentIndex) {
        //incluir el delta en el índice
        return pGroup[deltaGroup + i];
    }
}
```